# Is it possible to display a form before a component/form is destroyed?

Tags: delphi, components, vcl, delphi-5

I am working in Delphi5

I would like to have a custom form appear before a component is destroyed at runtime of a project.

Is it possible to do this from within a Custom Component? In other words, can I display a form before the custom component is destroyed in runtime, when the form on which it is placed, is closed?

I have tried placing the following in the destructor of the component, but I get an access violation error when the form is closed:

```
destructor TqqFormLogger.Destroy;
begin
  if NOT (csDesigning in ComponentState) then
    SurveyForm.Click;

  inherited Destroy;
end;
```

Comment: It's no problem to do what you are trying to do. Impossible to say why it's not working for you. What is `SurveyForm`? Any chance of some more code so we can see where the AV is.

Comment: Sorry for not being that clear. What I have is a component called 'FormLogger' which is placed on all forms on our projects. At project runtime, this component creates a TButton (called SurveyButton) which, if clicked, opens up a form (SurveyForm). This part works fine up until now. However, we would like to have the SurveyForm open everytime a form is closed (i.e. have the SurveyButton.Click event triggered). It seems that when the SurveyButton.click is triggerd in the Destructor of my component, the main form that hosts the component is already destroyed. Is there a solution? Thank you

Comment: The Form automatically calls `FreeNotification()` on design-time components (which in turn calls the Form's `FreeNotification()` method).  Your component can override its `Notification()` method to detect when the Form is being freed. Alternatively, if you have any Forms that are not freed right away when closed, your component's constructor could assign an event handler to the Form's `OnClose` event.

Comment: Hi Remy, thank you for your suggestions. Could you please clarify how to implement your two suggestions above, especially how I could I assign or override my owner form's (the form on which the component resides) OnClose event?

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, an AV is a signal that some code tries to invoke a routine of something that does not exist anymore.

Seen in that light, an AV as result of this specific destructor could indicate one of two cases:

1. `SurveyForm` does not exist anymore, or
2. Code as result of `SurveyForm.Click` expects your component existence to be true, but the component is destroyed anyway.

The name `Click` suggests that `SurveyForm` is a button-like control. If that control is not part of your component but is part of the form on which the component resides, then the former (case 1) could certainly be true: the form's destructor has already destroyed `SurveyForm`, and is now about to destroy your component. You could prevent this by making use of `BeforeDestruction` as Remy already mentioned. Also (but just as general tip, not as a solution to your problem), you can prevent using a destroyed component by registering that component to your own to be notified of its destruction. Do this with `FreeNotification` in combination with overriding `Notification` in which you nil the component:

```
procedure TqqFormLogger.SetSurveyForm(Value: TForm);
begin
  FSurveyForm := Value;
  FSurveyForm.FreeNotification(Self);
end;

procedure TqqFormLogger.Notification(AComponent: TComponent;
  Operation: TOperation);
begin
  inherited Notification(AComponent, Operation);
  if (AComponent = FSurveyForm) and (Operation = opRemove) then
    FSurveyForm := nil;
end;

destructor TqqFormLogger.Destroy; 
begin
  if FSurveyForm <> nil then
    ...
```

If the control is indeed part of your component, then I suspect the code behind `Click` allows the proceding of the component's destructor anyhow (case 2). For example, when posting a message (manually or as a result of VCL's or Windows internals), `inherited Destroy` will be called before the message will arive or be handled.

In short: right now the question is too general to give a specific answer.

Comment: `SurveyForm` would still live at the point at which the `Click` method is called because it doesn't die until `TComponent.Destroy` executes.

Comment: +1 Any time a component has a reference to an external componnt, it is a good idea to use `FreeNotification()` in case the external component gets freed prematurely or out-of-order.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: but we don't know yet when/where `SurveyForm.Destroy` is being called in relation to `TqqFormLogger.Destroy`, or even if `SurveyForm` is the same object as `TqqFormLogger`'s parent form.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Which is why any answer at the moment relies heavily on guess work.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at overriding the `BeforeDestruction()` method instead of the destructor.

But why do that at the component layer?  Why not do it in the parent Form's `OnClose` event instead?

Comment: Why would this make any difference? Presumably the issue is that SurveyForm is no good. And that will be the case in BeforeDestruction, OnClose etc.

Comment: `BeforeDestruction()` is called before any destructors, so it is a good place for a class to do things before its destructors (especially implicit destructors) have a chance to touch anything. But more importantly, the parent Form's `OnClose` event is triggered way before any of the Form's child controls start being destroyed, so this could be a timing issue with `SurveyForm` being freed after the parent Form is closed but before `TqqFormLogger` is destroyed.

Comment: To simplyfy my question: Is it possible for to have component control or interupt it's parent (owner) form's close event (destruction) process, in order to do some processing of it's own before the form closes?

Comment: Not to control/interrupt, no.  But calling `FreeNotification()` on the Form, you can receive a notification when the Form is in the act of being freed.

Comment: Hi Remy, on my component's create constructor I placed Owner.FreeNotification(self). Then, I overrite the Notification event of my component with the following: If AComponent.Name = Owner.Name then SurveyForm.ShowModal. However, this still does not work. I suppose because the parent (owner) form closes without waiting to display my surveyform.

Comment: You don't need to call `FreeNotification()` on the Owner manually, the `TComponent` constructor does that for you. When comparing the components in `Notification()`, compare the actual object pointers directly, not their `Name` values, eg: `if AComponent = Owner then`.

Comment: Hi Remy, thanks for your kind help, I will try the above. In your suggestion on the top of this post, you mention the alternative of having my component's constructor assign an event handler to the Form's OnClose event. Could you explain or show me code how this can be done? Thank you.

Comment: `constructor TqqFormLogger.Create(AOwner: TComponent); begin inherited; if AOwner is TCustomForm then TCustomForm(AOwner).OnClose := FormClosed; end;  procedure TqqFormLogger.FormClosed(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction); begin ... end;`